# Accuracy in collision ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, collision

im making a game which there is a plane flying and some rocks that u need to avoid them by movin ur plane.in order to use collision detection i made a cube with the same position of my object but the accuracy is not even 50%.sometimes when my object has collision it wont tell me , and sometimes when the object is away it shows the alert that it had collision.

[image: Wrong Collision Detection Picture]

Collision Detection Code :

```
   if(collisiondetection === true) {
   var originPoint = obcube.position.clone();

    clearText();

    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < obcube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
    {
        var localVertex = obcube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
        var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( obcube.matrix );
        var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( obcube.position );

        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );

        var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collisionlist );
        if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) {
            if(alerted === false) {
                alerted = true;
 GameOver();
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Dodecahedron ( cubes for collision)

```
      var cubegeo = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(2,0);
      var cubemat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color:0x29CB1C,
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('rock.png'),   
 transparent:true,
  depthWrite:false,
   blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
     });
  var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(cubegeo,cubemat);

  cube1.position.z = -60;
  cube1.position.x = randomnumx1 ;
  cube1.position.y = randomnumy1;
  scene.add(cube1);
  cube1.name = "cuves";
  makeme=false;
   mycubes = scene.getObjectByName('cuves');
    collisionlist.push(cube1);
```

the cubes have both Z rotation and position changing, no x,y and i push the into an array collisionlist!
plane can change position x,y,z
"collisiondetection === true" is to make sure that all the cubes and plane are in the scene.
I put the cube and plane in a group but in collision detection i use obcube (wireframed cube)

Thanks in advance

Comment: forgot to mention that collision detection is in animate